# I have problem to install a NuGet Package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

When I try to download a NuGet package I get these errors:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'BulkyWeb',

> The local source 'C:\Users\PULSE Electronics\Desktop\allInOneNuget' doesn't exist

Can anyone tell me why that is, and how to fix it?

I tried in Visual Studio 2022 to install a package and I expected it to work well

Comment: Well presumably you've configured your NuGet sources to use C:\Users\PULSE Electronics\Desktop\allInOneNuget, and that directory doesn't exist. So you need to fix your NuGet source configuration...

Comment: Thanks for your answers! i fixed it i just had to remove Package source from Package sources that was C:\Users\PULSE Electronics\Desktop\allInOneNuget and update it then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the package source mentioned does not exist, you will need to remove it from the "Package Sources"